# What syntax for relative path to script in cron?

Tags: linux, cron

I have cron  job.

```
* * * * * root python /root/folder/script.py
```

/root/folder/script.py  - full path to script.

I need something like relative path to script.

```
* * * * * root python ~/folder/script.py
```

Cron must find 'folder' and execute script.py

I want to have freedom to put /folder/script.py   anywhere in filesystem.

Comment: crontab does not allow you to do so. You need to specify a full path. Maybe you can create a wrapper script with full path and from there you can call this one.

Comment: Won't work.. won't work..

Comment: `~` doesn't mean *anywhere* but instead *in your home directory*. And because of security reasons you certainly don't want to execute a random `script.py` as root.

Comment: thanks, but it's only example

Comment: maybe it's possible to make  one liner, something like '* * * * * find script.py | python script.py'  ?

Comment: Why can't you put that script at a dedicated place?  Could you put a different script at a dedicated place instead?  Then you could use that as a wrapper, finding and calling your original script.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  *   *    *    *            *           python $(getent passwd the-user | cut -d: -f6)/folder/script.py
```